# How can i execute jquery: mouseenter on a element using selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am trying to automate a scenario through selenium where I have to click on a menu element, I tried all except jQuery. I have tried normal WebDriver click, JavaScript `click()`, but nothing has worked. Can anyone please help me with jQuery in selenium.

html:

```
<tr class="popUpMenuItemLo" onmouseenter="HighlightItem(this);ShowSubMenu('submenu11');">
  <td align="middle" style="width:20px; background-Color:#FFF;"></td>
  <td nowrap="&nbsp">xyz</td>
  <td width="20px" align="right">
    <font face="webdings" size="2">4</font>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My code:

```
//created the javascriptexecutor instance js

IWebElement getElement = driver().FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[contains(text(),xyz"));
js.ExecuteScript("$(argument[0]).mouseenter();", getElement);
```

I am not getting the desired result where the `mouseenter` should be performed on the element.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?..We cant do mouse enter unless it is a input text field..Provide the DOM if possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: need to post HTML for the element

Comment: Hi santosh. I got  exception: {"JavaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)"} System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 0):

You can try with actions class `MoveToElement` and click methods. or with jQuery, try with `mouseover()` and `click()`:

```
js.ExecuteScript("$(argument[0]).mouseover();", getElement);
```

Comment: Hi Murthi. i tried it. but it doesn't work. Movetoelement moves the focus to some other element.. weird though.